# Opinions on IdeaBank?

Tags: .net, reference

I'm a PHP developer who is being considered for a job implementing [IdeaBank](http://www.brainbankinc.com/idealinkOpen.aspx), idea management software written in .net.  The software appears to have been selected based on its features and clients.  The [OpenDNS community](http://ideabank.opendns.com/) appears to be using it.

Is anyone familiar with this software?  What's it like to customize and maintain?  Would you recommend it to another programmer?

Comment: if they habitually employ PHP developers to implement their .NET software, then i probably would not recommend it ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update - I never did find anyone using IdeaBank, now know as [IdeaLink](http://www.brainbankinc.com/idealinkSequential.aspx), a product sold by [BrainBank](http://www.brainbankinc.com/about.aspx).  But they didn't offer me the position, so my problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the similar names, the IdeaBank community feature on OpenDNS has nothing to do with the .Net software you cite. It's based on Pligg, which uses PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Pligg.  I'd be a lot more comfortable working in PHP.  I'll suggest it as an alternative.